# Windows Mobile - ScrollViewer

Tags: silverlight, windows-mobile

I have a Windows Mobile application. Within that application, i've got a ScrollViewer which allows the user to flick through the many images which I have inside that scroller. In this case, they are images of the alphabet.

The problem is, I want *logical code* to execute when the user clicks on an image, BUT, if the user scrolls by clicking on the letter, it actuates the code....

For example, imageA has a LeftClickButton event, but...if the user scrolls by touching the letter A....the logical code in the imgA_LeftClick fires.

How do I overcome this problem? Below is my code.

```
<ScrollViewer Height="98" Name="scrollerButtons" Width="603" Canvas.Left="40" Canvas.Top="383" VerticalAlignment="Center" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <StackPanel Name="stackPanelButtons" Orientation="Horizontal" Canvas.Left="162" Canvas.Top="43" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">

                <Image Height="60" Name="imgA" Source="a.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="60"></Image>
                <Image Height="60" Name="imgK" Source="k.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="60"></Image>
                <Image Height="60" Name="imgM" Source="m.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="60" MouseLeftButtonDown="imgM_MouseLeftButtonDown"></Image>
                <Image Height="60" Name="imgJ" Source="j.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="60"></Image>
                <Image Height="60" Name="imgN" Source="n.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="60"></Image>
                <Image Height="60" Name="imgO" Source="o.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="60"></Image>
                <Image Height="60" Name="imgI" Source="i.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="60"></Image>
                <Image Height="60" Name="imgH" Source="h.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="60"></Image>
                <Image Height="60" Name="imgG" Source="g.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="60"></Image>
                <Image Height="60" Name="imgF" Source="f.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="60" MouseLeftButtonDown="imgF_MouseLeftButtonDown"></Image>
                <Image Height="60" Name="imgE" Source="e.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="60"></Image>
                <Image Height="60" Name="imgD" Source="d.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="60"></Image>
                <Image Height="60" Name="imgC" Source="c.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="60"></Image>
                <Image Height="60" Name="imgB" Source="b.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="60"></Image>
                <Image Height="60" Name="imgL" Source="l.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="60"></Image>
                <Image Height="60" Name="imgT" Source="t.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="60"></Image>
                <Image Height="60" Name="imgS" Source="s.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="60"></Image>
                <Image Height="60" Name="imgR" Source="r.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="60"></Image>
                <Image Height="60" Name="imgQ" Source="q.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="60"></Image>
                <Image Height="60" Name="imgP" Source="p.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="60"></Image>
                <Image Height="60" Name="imgU" Source="u.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="60"></Image>
                <Image Height="60" Name="imgZ" Source="z.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="60"></Image>
                <Image Height="60" Name="imgV" Source="v.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="60"></Image>
                <Image Height="60" Name="imgW" Source="w.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="60"></Image>
                <Image Height="60" Name="imgY" Source="y.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="60"></Image>
                <Image Height="60" Name="imgX" Source="x.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="60"></Image>
            </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: I'm just trying to be polite....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the `MouseLeftButtonDown` event, use the [Tap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.tap%28VS.95%29.aspx) event. Seeing as this is tagged Silverlight, I assume you mean `Windows Phone` and not `Windows Mobile`.

Comment: Hey there. Thanks for your comment. I typed in "Tap" in to my XML but it doesn't recognise it. Any ideas?

Comment: You mean `XAML` :) And `Tap` is an event the image control has http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image%28VS.95%29.aspx What error is it throwing?

Comment: Ah right, XAML, sorry :)

Well, I typed Tap="eventHandler" within the Image tag and it doesn't recognise Tap. I then checked the events list in the Image Control and it doesn't have tap...It has stuff like GotFocus, MouseLeave, MouseEnter, Loaded, LeftButton.... etc. But no Tap.

Comment: Are you sure you're creating a 7.1 Windows Phone project and not a 7.0 one?

Comment: It would've asked you when you created a new project. If you can't remember, open up you `WMAppManifest.xml` file in your `Properties` folder. In the `Deployment` section on the third line down, there is an attribute called `AppPlatformVersion`. It should say 7.1 if you're targeting the latest version.

Comment: Ah bugger. It says i'm using 7.0

Comment: There are other things you can do instead, but is there a reason you chose to target 7.0? Pretty much every Windows Phone user has moved on to Mango, so there's no real reason to target 7.0. If you don't need 7.0, you can upgrade by right-clicking on the solution and clicking `Upgrade to Windows Phone 7.1`.

Comment: I didn't have an option back then. When I made this project (Which was about 4 months ago) It didn't give me an option.

Furthermore, I can't see an option for "Update to Windows Phone 7.1" when I right-click the solution. Any idea as to why I can't see it?

Your help is HIGHLY appreciated.

Comment: You need to install the latest SDK: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27570 Read the release notes for installation instructions.